# Bash move all files with same name to a new directory with that name

Tags: bash

In my `Plex` movies directory I want to move all my media and subtitle files to their own directories rather than being in all in that folder. The video file types are not all the same. So at the moment the Movies directory looks something like this:

```
Alita Battle Angel (2019).en.srt
Alita Battle Angel (2019).m4v
Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004).mp4
Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004).srt
Ant-Man (2015).en.srt
Ant-Man (2015).m4v
Ant-Man and the Wasp (2018).en.srt
Ant-Man and the Wasp (2018).m4v
Aquaman (2018).en.srt
Aquaman (2018).m4v
Argo (2012).en.forced.srt
Argo (2012).en.srt
Argo (2012).m4v
...
```

I want to move each video file and any subtitle files to a directory with the same name:

```
Alita Battle Angel (2019)
Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004)
Ant-Man (2015)
...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've looked at other similar problems and this script is sort of working on a test directory but I don't want it mess up my library if there is a better way:

```
for f in *; do
[[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
  dir="${f%.*}"
  mkdir "$dir"
  mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I've done it for this time

Comment: When doing anything like this, 1) make sure you have a good, up-to-date backup first, 2) use `mv -i` or `mv -n` to avoid overwriting files in case of a name conflict, and 3) try a dry run first, with `echo` in front of the `mkdir` and `mv` commands, to get an idea what it'll do when you run it for real.

Comment: In your shown code I suggest to replace `%` with `%%` to strip `.en.srt` from `Alita Battle Angel (2019).en.srt` and not just `.srt`.

Comment: The script you copied assumed that files only have a single extension, not double extensions like `.en.srt`.

Comment: Consider using `[[ -s "$f" ]] || continue` which ensures the file (1) exits and (2) is non-zero in size (if you want to omit zero length files)

Answer (score 1):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
for file in *; do
    dir="${file%)*})"
    echo mkdir -p "$dir"
    echo mv "$file" "$dir/"
done
```

Remove `echo` statement when you are happy with the output.

##### Output:

```
$ tree
.
├── Alita Battle Angel (2019)
│   ├── Alita Battle Angel (2019).en.srt
│   └── Alita Battle Angel (2019).m4v
├── Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004)
│   ├── Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004).mp4
│   └── Anchorman The Legend of Ron Burgundy (2004).srt
├── Ant-Man (2015)
│   ├── Ant-Man (2015).en.srt
│   └── Ant-Man (2015).m4v
├── Ant-Man and the Wasp (2018)
│   ├── Ant-Man and the Wasp (2018).en.srt
│   └── Ant-Man and the Wasp (2018).m4v
├── Aquaman (2018)
│   ├── Aquaman (2018).en.srt
│   └── Aquaman (2018).m4v
└── Argo (2012)
    ├── Argo (2012).en.forced.srt
    ├── Argo (2012).en.srt
    └── Argo (2012).m4v

6 directories, 13 files
```